# If statement inside php content, containing html code

Tags: php, html

```
<?php

    $content = "

            <table style='text-align: center;'>
                <tr>
                    <td style='text-align: center;'>
                       ".$result->name."
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

I have the above code, and I would like to know, if i can add an `if` statement inside `style` of 2nd `td`, so `if ($result->name == ""){display: none;}` .

Is there any way that this can happen ?

Notice that if name exists the above code will print the name, if not it will print an empty `td` .

Thanks in advance!

Comment: sure you can. Just break the concatenation, add an if that conditionally concatenates 'display:none;' and then concatenate the rest of the table

Comment: Ternary operator will help you.

Comment: Yes - you could a) use a ternary operator b) assign the class to a variable beforehand and include that in the echo c) break the `$content` var into bits and concatenate it with `.=` d) break it into bits with PHP *template style* syntax .... have I missed any?

Comment: if I break the concatenation, should then use a variable inside if statement including `display: none` and add it to next `.=` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a few ways you can do it:

**1: Use a [Ternary Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)**

```
<?php
$content = "

    <table style='text-align: center;'>
        <tr>
            <td style='text-align: center;" . ($result->name ? " display: none;" : "") . "'>
                {$result->name}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
";
```

**2: Assign the CSS to a variable and interpolate it**

```
<?php
$css = $result->name ? " display: none;" : "";
$content = "

    <table style='text-align: center;'>
        <tr>
            <td style='text-align: center;{$css}'>
                {$result->name}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
";
```

**3: Break the $content variable assignment into bits so you can use an if() condition**

```
<?php
$content = "

    <table style='text-align: center;'>
        <tr>
            <td style='text-align: center;";

if($result->name) $content .= " display: none;";

$content .= "'>
                {$result->name}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
";
```

**4: Use PHP's *template* style syntax**

```
<table style='text-align: center;'>
    <tr>
        <td style='text-align: center;<?php if($result->name): ?> display: none;<?php endif; ?>'>
            <?= $result->name; ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is my preferred option if you're working in a template (a `.phtml` file for example).

**5: ... or mix it up a bit** (template style with a ternary echo)

```
<table style='text-align: center;'>
    <tr>
        <td style='text-align: center;<?= $result->name ? " display: none;" : ""; ?>'>
            <?= $result->name; ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Ultimately it comes down to which you find most readable and are most comfortable with.

Comment: Ugh, curly braces. ;) But yes, this covers them all.

Comment: @IncredibleHat - heh sorry, I try to limit them to only iddy biddy bits when interpolating variables, I promise :)

Comment: I prefer fourth answer as well, but im going with the Ternary Operator!

Comment: You'd be amazed how you end up using them all... for all kinds of situations. Especially when dealing with any old code you are stumbling over lol.

Comment: I just used the first one and i have a syntax error " Syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting... "

Comment: @AlcaeusD - sorry, I got carried away with the curly braces (\*ahem\*) try it now.

Comment: I am also trying to do it please see my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63148838/how-to-properly-view-table-data-using-if-statement-in-yii2)

Answer (score 2):

Sure, use the ternary operator...

```
$content = "<table style='text-align: center;'>
               <tr>
                   <td style='text-align: center;" . ($result->name == 'Foo Bar' ? ' display:none;' : '') . "'>
                      ".$result->name."
                   </td>
               </tr>
           </table>"
```

Comment: David Walsh has a great article on it... https://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators

Comment: It seems that this works but my question is, should I replace `$condition` with `$result->name`, since the `$result->name` 's value is the one that determines if the `td` should be displayed or not ?

Comment: Sure. I've updated the answer for you. Just set your condition to match whatever you are checking for.

Comment: I am also trying to do it please see my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63148838/how-to-properly-view-table-data-using-if-statement-in-yii2)

Answer (score 1):

You sure can! This is a perfect opportunity to use a ternary statement. Let me explain.

A ternary statement looks like this:

```
<?php
$condition = true;
$content = 'Condition is ' . ( ($condition === true) ? 'met' : 'not met' ) . 'and some more text'; 
// Outputs 'Condition is met and some more text' because condition is true
?>
```

Essentially it allows you to write inline conditional statements. Sometimes they're not very readable, but sometimes they in fact make the surrounding code more readable.

Comment: Here's the PHP docs on the subject of [ternary operators](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

Comment: I am also trying to do it please see my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63148838/how-to-properly-view-table-data-using-if-statement-in-yii2)