# How to properly view table data using if statement in yii2

Tags: php, html, html-table, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am working on `yii2`. I have a page in which I have created a table. Now I want to put some data into it via my database query using `if....else` statement.

```
<tbody style="text-align: center; line-height: 12px">
<?php
                    $bd = $dataProvider2->getModels();
                    foreach ($bd as $a)
                    {
                        $strt =$a['slab_start'];
                        $end = $a['slab_end'];
                        $rate = $a['rate'];
                        if ($end !='')
                        {
                            echo "<tr>
                                <td>".print_r($strt).".".print_r('-').".".print_r($end)."</td>
                                <td>".print_r($rate)."</td>

                            </tr>";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            echo "<tr>
                                <td>".print_r('upto')."</td>
                                <td>".print_r($rate)."</td>

                            </tr>";
                        }
                    }

                    ?>
</tbody>
```

But when I try to view my page, the above data is not properly shown

[image]

It's not going inside the `<tbody>`.

**Expected output**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't use print_r inside echo:

```
<tbody style="text-align: center; line-height: 12px">
<?php
                    $bd = $dataProvider2->getModels();
                    foreach ($bd as $a)
                    {
                        $strt =$a['slab_start'];
                        $end = $a['slab_end'];
                        $rate = $a['rate'];
                        if ($end !='')
                        {
                            echo "<tr>
                                <td>".$strt ."-". $end ."</td>
                                <td>".$rate."</td>

                            </tr>";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            echo "<tr>
                                <td>upto</td>
                                <td>".$rate."</td>

                            </tr>";
                        }
                    }

                    ?>
</tbody>
```